# trigger on Account to update contact(whenever account billingaddress is updated contact mailing address also gets updated)

Tags: visualforce

```
Trigger CaseAfterInsertUpdate on Account(after insert, after update) {
    List<Contact> accList = new List<Contact>();
for(Account c:Trigger.new){
system.debug('hfeffht'+c.id);
system.debug('hfeffht'+c.ID);
Contact con=new Contact(LastName=c.Name,
 MailingStreet=c.BillingStreet,
                MailingCity=c.BillingCity,
                MailingPostalCode=c.BillingPostalCode,
                MailingCountry=c.BillingCountry,
        AccountId=c.ID);
         accList.add(con);
         system.debug('AccountId'+con.AccountId);
}
try {
        upsert accList;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.debug('Could not update Last Survey Sent field on Account with cause: ' + ex.getCause());
    }
   }
```

here the problem is,if i am trying to insert record means working good copying address,if updating record means a again it is creating a new record,not updating the exist.

Comment: Is there a reason Process Builder couldn't be used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upsert will do two operations.
1. Insert records if Id is not specified 
2. Update if Id is specified.

You didn't specify contact Id in the list for the update.so Upsert will always insert new record.

When account get updated you need to query contacts under that account and update those contact records.

```
trigger CaseAfterInsertUpdate on Account(after insert, after update) {

    List<Contact> accList = new List<Contact>();
    Map<Id,List<Contact>> AccountMap = new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();

    if(Trigger.isUpdate){

        for(Contact con : [SELECT Id,AccountId FROM C0ntact WHERE AccountId IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()])

            if(!AccountMap.containskey(con.AccountId){
                AccountMap.put(con.AccountId,new List<Contact>());
            }
            AccountMap.get(con.AccountId).add(con); 
        }
    }

    for(Account c:Trigger.new) {

        system.debug('hfeffht'+c.ID);

        if(!AccountMap.containskey(c.Id)) { //code for insert only

            Contact con = new Contact(LastName=c.Name,
                                MailingStreet=c.BillingStreet,
                                MailingCity=c.BillingCity,
                                MailingPostalCode=c.BillingPostalCode,
                                MailingCountry=c.BillingCountry,
                                AccountId=c.ID);
            accList.add(con);
            system.debug('AccountId'+con.AccountId);

         }else { //code for update account

            for(Contact con : AccountMap.get(c.Id)){ //get all contacts under account and update.

                con.MailingCity = c.BillingCity;
                con.MailingPostalCode = c.BillingPostalCode;
                con.MailingCountry = c.BillingCountry;
                accList.add(con);
            }
         }
    }


    try {
        upsert accList;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.debug('Could not update Last Survey Sent field on Account with cause: ' + ex.getCause());
    }
}
```

Comment: hi maha,this is  xactly what i want ,,thanq.

Comment: hi maha,in addition to this trigger,i designed vf page to save account,problem here is two records are created

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccBillToConMai">

<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton value="submit" action="{!save}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageBlockSection >
<apex:inputField value="{!a.Name}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!a.phone}" required="true"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!a.Industry}" required="true"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!a.BillingStreet}" required="true"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!a.BillingPostalCode}" required="true"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>

Comment: public with sharing class AccBillToConMai {
public Account a{get;set;}
    public AccBillToConMai(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
a=(Account)controller.getRecord();
    }
    
    public pageReference save(){
    
    try {
    
    insert a;

        ID acctID = a.ID;
system.debug('acctID '+acctID);
    // Add a contact to this account.
    Contact con = new Contact(
        
        LastName=a.Name,
                MailingStreet=a.BillingStreet,
                MailingCity=a.BillingCity,
MailingPostalCode=a.BillingPostalCode,
              MailingCountry=a.BillingCountry,

Comment: AccountId=acctID);
        if(a.Industry=='Construction'){
        con.Company_Name__c=a.Name;
        con.Company_Phone__c=a.Phone;
        insert con;
        return null;
        }else if(a.Industry=='Education'){
        con.University__c='svc';
        con.private__c=true;
        insert con;
        }else if(a.Industry=='Electronics'){
        con.devices__c='Ac';
  con.review__c='2';insert con;
}
insert con;
} catch(DmlException e) {
System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
}pageReference pf=new pageReference ('/'+a.Id);
pf.setRedirect(true);
 return pf;}}

Comment: you used this page to create a new account ? or update existing account as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem was due to line `AccountId =c.Id,`
In case of `upsert` operation,first it checks whether record is existing or not,if not then create a new record.

In the line `AccountId = c.id` ,It doesn't determine the existence of Contact Record,Since you have used DML operation for Contact Object.

Use `Map<Id,Account>,` this will sort out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new instance of contact everytime for loop executes and doing upsert operation. Try this

```
trigger updateContact on Account (After update) {

    list<account> accList = [select id,name, billingCity,(select id, MailingCity from contacts) from account where id in :trigger.newMap.keyset()];
    list<contact> conList = new list<contact>();
    for(account acc: accList){          
        if(trigger.oldMap.containskey(acc.id) && trigger.newMap.containskey(acc.id) && trigger.oldMap.get(acc.id).billingCity != trigger.newMap.get(acc.id).billingCity){
            for(contact c:acc.contacts){
                c.MailingCity = trigger.newMap.get(acc.id).billingCity;
                conList.add(c);
            }           
        }
    }
    update conList;
}
```

Comment: Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'list' at line 3 column 144,this is the error am getting

Comment: may be you are trying the same with after insert. My code was on after update only.

Comment: working fine,,thanq

Comment: trigger updateContact on Account (After update) {

list<Account> accList = [select id,name, billingCity,(select id, MailingCity from contacts) from account where id in :trigger.newMap.keyset()]; 
list<contact> conList = new list<contact>();

for(account acc: accList){

if(trigger.oldMap.containskey(acc.id) && trigger.newMap.containskey(acc.id) && trigger.oldMap.get(acc.id).billingCity != trigger.newMap.get(acc.id).billingCity){
    for(contact c:acc.contacts){
        c.MailingCity = trigger.newMap.get(acc.id).billingCity;
        conList.add(c);
    }
}
}
}

Comment: List error was coz in here when i paste code it looks good but when save changes then some code got changed somehow. like declaration of list of contacts. But you can try the logic applied here.

Comment: in case of error, declare list of account with query and list of contact properly. As it is skipping this here. I wonder.

Answer (score -1):

```
Trigger CaseAfterUpdate on Account(after insert, after update) {
    List<Contact> accList = new List<Contact>();
    for(Account c:Trigger.new){
        system.debug('hft'+c.id);
        system.debug('hft'+c.ID);
        Contact con=new Contact(LastName=c.Name,
        MailingStreet=c.BillingStreet,
                    MailingCity=c.BillingCity,
                    MailingPostalCode=c.BillingPostalCode,
                    MailingCountry=c.BillingCountry,
            AccountId=c.ID);
            accList.add(con);
            system.debug('AccountId'+con.AccountId);
    }
    try {
        upsert accList;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.debug('Could not update Last Survey Sent field on Account with cause: ' + ex.getCause());
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Right now, this answer is what we call a "code dump". It contains only code, and no explanation at to how it's supposed to work (or solve the problem at hand). These answers tend to generate a lot of back-and-forth in the comments like "that didn't work" and "try this instead", which makes it very hard to follow (especially for other people with similar, but different, issues). Good answers will tend to explain _what_ the problem is, _why_ it's a problem ,_how_ to fix it, and _why_ the fix works.